# UnrecognizedPropertyException with Jersey Jackson(Json)

Tags: java, jackson, jersey-client

I have the following response from Expedia EAN service

```
{
  "HotelListResponse": {
    ......
    "HotelList": {
          "@size": "200",
          "@activePropertyCount": "293",
          "HotelSummary": [....]
  ....
}
```

and the following code in my Jersey client

```
public <T> T get(String getUrl, Class<T> t) throws HttpOperationException{
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(getUrl);

    ClientResponse response = webResource
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);

    T output = response.getEntity(t);

    System.out.println(output);

    if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new HttpOperationException(
                response.getStatus(), output.toString());
    }

    return (T)output;
}
```

and I have invoked the client passing the HotelListResponse.class as well as Wrapper.class which I have created just as a container of HotelListResponse.class, both of which crashes with the below error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "HotelListResponse" (Class
>   in.xxx.xxxxxx.port.adapter.expedia.hotels.list.response.Wrapper), not
>   marked as ignorable

did I get my Object Model wrong here?

Comment: Can you show HotelListResponse.class and Wrapper.class?

Comment: I was able to diagnose the issue, it is because of the properties are being returned conditionally, included ``@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)``